# Convention for Discrete Asian / Lookback Options

Tags: asian-option

When computing the Payoff of Discrete Asian / Lookback Options (say 12 observations) using MC, does one usually use the value of S0 as well or only the latter realisations?

Best regards,
Alex

Comment: Not sure what you mean. $S_0$ is the "root" of all paths so yes you need it. Whether or not $t=0$ is an Asian fixing then depends on the term sheet of the contract to be priced. This is not frequent in practice in my experience though.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant t=0 as a fixing date or not, thanks!

Comment: Same for Discrete Lookback Options? it is usually not included in the min/max calculation?